# CSRf attack in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to prevent CSRf attack in Sharepoint 2010 .
My master page is custom SharePoint:FormDigest is there, still CSRF attack is possible.
Please provide me good detailed solution.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am running a SP2016 on-premise. No custom function. However the scanning test still fail on CSRF attack test. Is SharePoint really have CSRF protection?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has some guidance for dealing with security for custom solutions in SharePoint 2010.  It includes some information about how to deal with cross-site request forgery: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552614(v=office.14).aspx.

Comment: Hi John thanks for you instant reply can u please give me gud solution this article is covering best practices which i already gone through.